# TypeScript inference on typed constraints

Tags: typescript

I have some types which describe Api Calls. As an example:

```
export class RequestType {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}

export class ResponseType {
  prop3: string;
  prop4: string;
}
```

Each request type is linked to a Response type. What I'm currently doing is defining an interface `IReturn<T>` and add it to the request type:

```
export interface IReturn<T> {}

export class RequestType implements IReturn<ResponseType> {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}
```

Then I have a service, and I would like to have a method infer both request and response types from the constructor of the request type:

```
import { RequestType, IReturn } from './dto';

export class SomeService {
    callApi<TRequest extends IReturn<TResponse>, TResponse>(dto: Request) TResponse {
      // implementation
    }
}
```

When I try to call the service, however, TypeScript infers correctly `TRequest`, but `TResponse` gets bound to `{}`.

```
// response is a {} and not a ResponseType!!
const response = this.someService.call(requestInstance);
```

I'm a bit at a loss, now. How could I refactor either the service, the interfaces or the dtos in order to get type inference on *both* request and response types?

Comment: What is `TResponse`?

Comment: `callApi<TRequest extends IReturn<TResponse>, TResponse>` The idea is that I constraint the parameter to be a TRequest, AND TRequest must be an `IReturn<TResponse>`. `TResponse` is the second generic parameter, and should be resolved into `ResponseType`. I'm open to every possible alternative: what I want is an api that "knows" that if I pass a `RequestType` the returned type should be `ResponseType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here, the first one is that you have unused generic parameters, since typescript uses a structural type system these are pretty much ignored. You can see this documented in this [faq](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ). The second problem is that typescript will not do type inference to guess `TResponse` when `TRequest extends IReturn<TResponse>` it will just go for the simplest possible `TResponse` which is usually `{}`.

To get around these limitations, we can firstly use the type parameter in `IReturn<T>`, for example we can have a field representing the constructor of `T` (but really any usage will do, even a dummy one say `_unusedField: T`). And for the second issue we can use a conditional type to extract the `T` from `IReturn<T>`:

```
export class ResponseType {
    prop3: string;
    prop4: string;
}

export interface IReturn<T> { returnCtor : new (...args: any[] ) => T; }

export class RequestType implements IReturn<ResponseType> {
    returnCtor = ResponseType;
    prop1!: string;
    prop2!: string;
}

export class SomeService {
    callApi<TRequest extends IReturn<any>>(dto: TRequest) : TRequest extends IReturn<infer U> ? U : never {
        return null as any
    }
}

const someService = new SomeService;
const requestInstance = new RequestType;
const response = someService.callApi(requestInstance);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ResponseType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop4%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IReturn%3CT%3E%20%7B%20returnCtor%20%3A%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%20)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20RequestType%20implements%20IReturn%3CResponseType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20returnCtor%20%3D%20ResponseType%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1!%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2!%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20SomeService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callApi%3CTRequest%20extends%20IReturn%3Cany%3E%3E(dto%3A%20TRequest)%20%3A%20TRequest%20extends%20IReturn%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20never%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20someService%20%3D%20new%20SomeService%3B%0D%0Aconst%20requestInstance%20%3D%20new%20RequestType%3B%0D%0Aconst%20response%20%3D%20someService.callApi(requestInstance)%3B%0D%0Aresponse.prop3%0D%0Aresponse.prop4)

Comment: The idea is sound. Thanks! And thanks for infer, which I didn't knew. If I copy the code in VS Code, however, `response` is guessed as `{}`. I'm on TS 2.9.1. Does it work for you?

Comment: Strange... it works if I copy the code in another file. Probably it's some conflict on my side. Marking the question as solved! You're the man!

Comment: @A.Chiesa yes it does, added playground link as proof :)